# More than two streams in a row?

Tags: node.js

I can't get two streams in a row to work in node.js. See the following code:

```
var Stream = require('stream');

var stream1 = new Stream;
stream1.readable = true;

var stream2 = new Stream;
stream2.readable = stream2.writable = true;

var stream3 = new Stream;
stream3.readable = stream3.writeable = true;

var i = 0;

stream2.write = function(data){this.emit('data', data)};
stream3.write = function(data){this.emit('data', data)};

setInterval((function() {
stream1.emit('data', String(i++));
}), 100);

//works:
stream1.pipe(stream2).pipe(process.stdout);

//does not work - why???
//stream1.pipe(stream2).pipe(stream3).pipe(process.stdout);
```

How do I get the two streams in a row to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will feel very stupid , its a typo error:

```
stream2.readable = stream2.writable = true;
stream3.readable = stream3.writeable = true;
```

See the difference, an extra `e` in `stream3.writable`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm surprised that no error was thrown for that.

Answer (score 0):

try [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) (or from [nmpjs.com](https://npmjs.org/package/async)) - the most popular Node.js module for working with asynchronous JavaScript with examples and wiki.